# MacBook Keeps Waking Up

Tags: terminal, mac, sleep-wake

My MacBook keeps waking up every 5 minutes or so. I ran "log show --style syslog | fgrep "Wake reason" " in Terminal and this was the output:

```
rydercragie@Ryders-MacBook-Pro-5 ~ % log show --style syslog | fgrep "Wake reason"
2022-03-03 00:21:53.575468+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 00:37:57.398816+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 00:42:59.903523+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2022-03-03 00:42:59.903530+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2022-03-03 00:42:59.979379+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2022-03-03 00:42:59.979386+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2022-03-03 00:43:00.279651+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (corecapture) 103112.541094 wlan0.A[13087] systemWokenByWiFi@39704:Wake reason = ARPT, kern.wakereason: 'EC.ARPT ARPT'
2022-03-03 00:43:00.279661+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleBCMWLANCoreMac) Wake reason = ARPT, kern.wakereason: 'EC.ARPT ARPT'
2022-03-03 00:43:00.526849+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 00:43:04.654468+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 00:43:04.670209+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 00:43:05.263130+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 00:43:16.807788+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2022-03-03 00:43:16.807793+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2022-03-03 01:13:12.410341+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2022-03-03 01:13:12.410346+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2022-03-03 01:13:13.400571+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:13:17.438445+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:13:17.456568+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:13:17.891044+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:21:04.416280+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2022-03-03 01:21:04.416286+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2022-03-03 01:23:55.968286+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2022-03-03 01:23:55.968309+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2022-03-03 01:23:56.858474+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:24:00.751789+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:24:00.766422+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:24:01.306821+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:24:59.817980+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2022-03-03 01:24:59.817987+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2022-03-03 01:28:19.145659+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2022-03-03 01:28:19.145665+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2022-03-03 01:28:19.443435+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (corecapture) 105831.603011 wlan0.A[13331] systemWokenByWiFi@39704:Wake reason = ARPT, kern.wakereason: 'EC.ARPT ARPT'
2022-03-03 01:28:19.443442+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleBCMWLANCoreMac) Wake reason = ARPT, kern.wakereason: 'EC.ARPT ARPT'
2022-03-03 01:28:20.082977+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:28:24.072566+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:28:24.087000+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:28:24.498491+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:29:16.323798+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2022-03-03 01:29:16.323804+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2022-03-03 01:35:55.330239+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2022-03-03 01:35:55.330243+0000  localhost corespeechd[1036]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2022-03-03 01:35:56.246935+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:36:00.223100+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:36:00.240862+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2022-03-03 01:36:01.084459+0000  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
```

I have Siri completely disabled. Does anyone know how to stop this?

Comment: 1. What major and minor version of macOS are you running? 2. Does this still happen if you first turn AirPort off before sleeping?

Comment: I am running the latest public release of Monterey and I do not use AirPort.

Comment: I have the same problem (CSGibraltarVoiceTriggerHandler listed as a "Wake reason") but occurring precisely every 2 hours instead of 5 minutes. I'm using macOS 12.3.1 and have never enabled Siri on this computer. Battery drains when computer is left unplugged, even though everything I can think of ("Power Nap", etc.) is disabled while on battery power. The drain appears to be in steps, consistent with what one would expect from periodic wake-ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pmset -a tcpkeepalive 0` solved it for me. But it kills Find My Mac, JFYI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm my MBP M1 was heating while being "asleep", found out `host` was the reason it was kept semi awake, and disabling `tcpkeepalive` did reduce its temperature while sleeping. Nevertheless, this is a huge regression, older MBP used to be network-alive while sleeping and never had this king of heating issues.